# how to fetch products in laravel using regexp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am facing problem. I want to find the products that belongs to current product (category_ids). I am in product detail page. Here is my structure of table:-
[image]

Now see currently i open the 2 product in browser and having category_ids(4,2) now i want to fetch all the products having the category_id 4 or 2 in my case i want to fetch the 3rd product but its is not working.. see 3rd product having category_id (1,2,6) so i want to fetch that record ... So if open 3rd product in browser i want o fetch the 2 product.. hope you guys undertstand here is my code:-

```
$recomendedProducts = Product::with('product_image')
                     ->whereRaw("category_ids REGEXP '".$productDetail['category_ids']. "'")
                      ->where('id','!=',$productDetail['id'])
                     ->inRandomorder()
                      ->take(5)
                      ->get();
```

This above query shows me empty result. Please help me how to resolve. I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: Excuse me, but why are you not using many to many relation?

Comment: i am working on filters. One product belongs to many categories..

Comment: Yes, you have a product that belongs to many categories and your category have many products.  If you set a many to many relation between them you can do any kind of filtering easily.

Comment: So if open 3rd product in browser above query must return records with id 1,2 and 6?

Comment: Your idea to store the categories as CSV is a bad one.  You are already seeing that it can cause problems when querying.  Rather than giving you an answer, I am suggesting that you improve your table design.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so how i can store give some suggestion?

Comment: Create a junction table which related products to categories.  Each row would contain one product-category relation.

Comment: @kunal https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships here is a documentation

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you mean i have to create one more table having these columns like product_id, category_id ? i am right

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i think you are right .. :) i have to change the structure of table

Comment: Just so i know what do you want for your final result, you have a product page, and want to display more products from the same category in that page? something like "related to" section in your page?

Comment: yes i want like that

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that is what you want, according to your comment, you can do it like this.

First, you need to create a proper relationship between your productucs and your categories.

On your **product** model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

On your **category** model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Next, you need to creat a proper pivot table to connect those two models. So create a migration for that.

`php artisan make:migration create_category_product_table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoryProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category_product');
    }
}
```

Now you can make a little function and access it and send it to your views via controller:

```
public function getRelatedProducts($product){
      $related_category_ids = $product->category()->pluck('categories.id');
      return $relatedProducts = Product::whereHas('category', function ($q) use($related_category_ids) {
        $q->whereIn('category_id', $related_category_ids);
    })
        ->where('id', '<>', $product->id)
        ->take(4)
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->get();
}
```